# Sharing VPN connection via Internet Connection Sharing without affecting desktop browsing

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, openvpn, ics

**Background**-
I have 2 NIC's on my desktop with first NIC connected to my main router providing internet. The 2nd NIC is connected to the WAN port of another router.

I have started a VPN connection (OpenVPN or L2TP) and shared this with my 2nd NIC to broadcast as a VPN WiFi via second router. This arrangement is currently working.

**Requirement**-
Currently, when I use this desktop's internet locally, I will be routed via the VPN connection. I do not want this. I want my desktop to still use 1st NIC internet. I want the VPN connection to solely be use for Internet Connection Sharing with the 2nd NIC.

**What I have tried-**
Changing Metrics in network adapter IPv4 advanced settings
(For L2TP only) Unchecking 'Use Default Gateway on remote Network' option

I would appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are having a routing issue. From what you have written, sounds like you have a pretty firm grip on networking, I expect this [webpage (on tcpip routing in windows)](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/adding-a-tcpip-route-to-the-windows-routing-table/) plus the page(s) it links to will get you your answer.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would say I am decent with networking, but can grasp concepts being from technical background.
Relating to the link you posted, I need to add a destination network IP, which in my case, is every network since I kinda want all browser routing (except packets from my NIC 2) to happen through that gateway directly instead of the TAP adapter enabled by the VPN.


My temporary solution is to setup an Ubuntu VM and bridge my NIC 2 directly to it to make sure my windows environment is isolated.